# jQuery: Smooth width changing on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jQuery code that is working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
            var scroll_pos = 0;
            $(document).scroll(function() { 
                scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
                 if(scroll_pos < 10 ) {
                    $("div").css('width', 75);
                } else if(scroll_pos > 25 && scroll_pos < 75) {
                    $("div").css('width', 100);
                } else if(scroll_pos > 75 && scroll_pos < 100){
                    $("div").css('width', 125);
                }else if(scroll_pos > 100){
                    $("div").css('width', 150);
         } 
    });
});
```

and a div element with width:75px at start.

With that code when user scroll down dive element is changing width from 75px to 150px in four steps, but I'm looking for something that will change that width from 75px to 150px smoothly without steps, any idea?

Comment: can you add html contetn in this link  http://jsfiddle.net/msasozbg/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/msasozbg/6/

Comment: Instead of `.css` use `.animate`. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/msasozbg/8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this solution is what you try to get:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_pos > 150) {
            scroll_pos = 150;
        };
        $("div").animate({
            width : (75+0.75*scroll_pos)+"px"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is good, but how to stop is at 150px? Right now it is bigger and bigger :)

Comment: use an if-else condition that will let the extend if it's less than or equal to 150px.

Comment: The answer has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for [***.animate()***](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) in jQuery. Just change the size of your div on scroll using animate.

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $(document).scroll(function() { 
        $("div").animate({
            width : "150px"
        });
    });
});
```

For continuous increment of width on scroll try this way. This will increment the width of div on each scroll with 30px and will increase until it reaches 150px.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if($("div").width() <= "150"){
            $("div").animate({
                width : "+=30"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/3ajg1f3n/)

***References :*** [***.scroll()***](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) , [***.animate()***](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: when u scroll down size is not reduces.

Comment: @Prashant, if you notice carefully, my 'jsFiddle' has comment that this test case is for incremental process. I just showed a way to get your work done. Not going to do your home work. If you've downvoted then you need more strong reason.

Comment: i checked question , user doesn't want reset or decrease width. I will up vote ur answer after some time.